# Animating a variable with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm building a page with a sidebar menu on the left and scrolling content on the right. When the user clicks one of these links in the menu I want the corresponding div to flash once, after the content is finished scrolling.

To achieve this I wrote this code:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    var banner = $(this).attr('href') + '.overlay';
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(banner).animate({'opacity':'1'},50);
    }, 800);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(banner).animate({'opacity':'0'},50);
    }, 850);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="banner" id="first">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="banner" id="second">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#first">   
     <li>Antifouling</li>
</a>
<a href="#second">  
    <li>Strak in de was</li>
</a>
```

*CSS*

```
.banner {
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin-bottom: 20px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
position:relative;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.overlay {
position: absolute;
top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 100;
}
```

The output of the variable "banner" when clicking on a#first would be #first.overlay

Now it turns out I can't use `.animate` on a variable. Is there a way to solve this problem or do I need to look elsewhere?

Comment: what is the value of the variable banner?

Comment: _"Now it turns out I can't use .animate on a variable"_ - Why do you think you cannot do this? What should happen? What is (not) happening instead? Is `banner` a valid selector? Is there a element in the DOM which should be found by the selector?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: The thing is though, the selector 'banner' is not working... I think this is because it's a variable but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok what is banner should be??

Comment: Banner is a combination of the link you clicked on (#first for example) and '.overlay'. Together this makes #first.overlay and this is the div I want changed. However, so far I'm not succeeding.

Comment: First of all, the markup you've added is invalid. And where are the elements with class `overlay`? Shouldn't it be `$(this).attr('href') + ".banner"`?

Comment: I've added the entire thing now. please don't confuse .banner and the variable banner. Sorry for that...

Comment: try to alert(banner)  and check if it has spaces

Comment: It doesn't have spaces

Comment: The html is still invalid. There are two closing </div>s to much, <li> elements are only allowed as direct childs of <ul> or <ol> and there are still no elements with the class overlay. Which elements should be found by the selector?

Comment: The extra </div> is an error I made when putting it on this website, I guess I didn't notice they were already there. I didn't copy the entire navigation because I thought it would irrelevant. And the overlay doesn't have any elements because it's supposed to appear and disappear very quickly making it look like a white flash. I just need to know if there is a way of animating the variable 'banner'.

Comment: The output of the 'banner' variable is this (based on what link you clicked' #first.overlay.

Comment: @Wijnand: http://jsfiddle.net/ohbnbstt/

Comment: You did it! Thanks a lot! @TahirAhmed